# Google sankey charts ordering data

Tags: php, google-visualization

I'm trying to use a sankey chart to display some marketing data. I'm struggling to get it to arrange the data in a meaningful order.

I have a query that extracts customer last order date and the last order date before that. I'm plotting a sankey chart but the order is all over the place.  I want to order the chart by the previous order date on the left hand side. I have ordered the query and the data is being outputted correctly. Does anyone know if I can achieve this and sort the chart?

Attached is an image of what I am getting. I need the dates on the left hand side to order descending.

[Chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYUL9.png)

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems that there isn't any reference to the order of nodes in the options object https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey.